# On submit keeps loading but not returning data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a form for making donation when user makes donation he will be viewing an error or if successful will be able to see a form on second page like second form will be loaded up. Now the problem is that when I tested data is properly updating in the database as well as on back end everything is working fine. The problem is that ajax is not getting return data I have placed a loader on success the loader will be hidden and it is not working it's continuously loading but not getting return data can anyone help me out to fix this error for me please here is my code

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.donate').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('.load').fadeIn(500);
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url         : "http://mydomainname.com/directory/user/makedonation",
            type        : "POST",
            data        : formData,
            contentType : false,
            cache       : false,
            processData : false,
            success     : function(data) {
                $('.load').fadeOut(500);
                console.log(data.status);
                $('.donation_form').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller User.php where the data is being processed

```
public function makedonation() {
    $comments  = $this->input->post('comments');
    $user_data = $this->get_data->user_info($this->session->userdata('uid'));
    $class     = $this->db->get_where('classes', array('id' => $user_data->row()->membership));
    $amount    = $class->row()->ammount_pay;
    $data      = array(
        'user_id'    => $user_data->row()->uid,
        'amount'     => $class->row()->ammount_pay,
        'rcv_amount' => $class->row()->ammount_receive,
        'class_id'   => $class->row()->id,
        'comments'   => $comments
    ); 

    $rt_data = $this->data_insert->donate_user($data);
        $rcv_data = $this->get_data->user_info($rt_data['receiver_id']);
        $name     = $rcv_data->row()->first_name . " " . $rcv_data->row()->last_name;
        $view_data = array(
            'user_id'        => $user_data->row()->uid,
            'receiver_id'    => $rt_data['receiver_id'],
            'transaction_id' => $rt_data['transaction_id'],
            'comments'       => $comments,
            'name'           => $name,
            'amount'         => $class->row()->ammount_pay,
            'command'        => 'Confirm Donation'
        );

        $this->load->view('user/includes/get_data', $view_data);
}
```

This is the modal where the data is being inserted into the database

```
public function donate_user($data) {
            $donation_data   = array(
                'user_id'         => $data['user_id'],
                'amount'          => $data['amount'],
                'receive_ammount' => $data['rcv_amount'],
                'date_deposit'    => date('m-d-Y'),
                'time_deposit'    => date('h:i A'),
                'class'           => $data['class_id'],
                'status'          => 'Submitted'
            );
            $insert_donation = $this->db->insert('donation', $donation_data);
            $transaction_id  = $this->db->insert_id();

            $rt_data = array(
                    'message'        => 'Success',
                    'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
                    'receiver_id'    => $receiver->row()->user_id
                );

            return $rt_data;
        }
```

Now here is my confusion if the data is inserting correctly into the data base and also when I run this file separately in the browser I am referring to my controller the second page is loading up properly no errors found the why ajax is not returning data

Comment: When are you submiting the form and one more thing, you should change ajax paramerter `typ:'POST'` to `method:'POST'`

Comment: Instead doing `$this->load->view('user/includes/get_data', $view_data);`, return `donate_user($data)` or create another method to handle ajax requests ant this method should return `donate_user($data)`

Comment: Done but still the same..On my controller when I Commented $this->load->view('user/includes/get_data', $view_data); and just placed echo "Hello World" it is working then

Comment: But how do I return some data as of wanted to load the whole file as of there is a second form in this file

Comment: can you please post an answer for me and let me know how do I do this I am bit confused by your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer. You have to set your ajax return data to json and do following in your controller.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.donate').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('.load').fadeIn(500);
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url         : "http://mydomainname.com/directory/user/makedonation",
            type        : "POST",
            data        : formData,
            contentType : false,
            cache       : false,
            processData : false,
dataType: 'json',
            success     : function(data) {
                $('.load').fadeOut(500);
                console.log(data.status);
                $('.donation_form').html(data.response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller Code

```
public function makedonation() {
    $comments  = $this->input->post('comments');
    $user_data = $this->get_data->user_info($this->session->userdata('uid'));
    $class     = $this->db->get_where('classes', array('id' => $user_data->row()->membership));
    $amount    = $class->row()->ammount_pay;
    $data      = array(
        'user_id'    => $user_data->row()->uid,
        'amount'     => $class->row()->ammount_pay,
        'rcv_amount' => $class->row()->ammount_receive,
        'class_id'   => $class->row()->id,
        'comments'   => $comments
    ); 

    $rt_data = $this->data_insert->donate_user($data);
        $rcv_data = $this->get_data->user_info($rt_data['receiver_id']);
        $name     = $rcv_data->row()->first_name . " " . $rcv_data->row()->last_name;
        $view_data = array(
            'user_id'        => $user_data->row()->uid,
            'receiver_id'    => $rt_data['receiver_id'],
            'transaction_id' => $rt_data['transaction_id'],
            'comments'       => $comments,
            'name'           => $name,
            'amount'         => $class->row()->ammount_pay,
            'command'        => 'Confirm Donation'
        );

        $result = $this->load->view('user/includes/get_data', $view_data,true);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('response' => $result,'status'=>'success')));

}
```

You can read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html for output and return view in variable to set as last parameter as true based on codeigniter feature of views.

Comment: You are awesome thumbs up for you i didn't knew about this it really helped me out thank you soo much

Comment: This is best way to  handle ajax request with mvc framework. .Thank you